# expanding keypath with lazyloading

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I have a full tree with multiple items and multiple levels, the tree is build with an ajax call and uses lazy nodes

So now i want to add the function so my tree can load and select and item if i give the full path, but before i can select the item i need to make sure that the item is loaded with  lazy loading so i can access it.

I found the function .loadKeypath(), so for testing i retrieved the full path to my node with

```
node.getKeyPath();
```

so the path is /12/16/17/18

So i figured out i should put this code after the ajax data was loaded in

```
onPostInit: function(isReloading, isError){
                $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").loadKeyPath("/12/16/17/18", function(node, status){
                    if(status == "loaded") {
                        // 'node' is a parent that was just traversed.
                        // If we call expand() here, then all nodes will be expanded
                        // as we go
                        node.expand();
                    }else if(status == "ok") {
                        // 'node' is the end node of our path.
                        // If we call activate() or makeVisible() here, then the
                        // whole branch will be exoanded now
                        node.activate();
                    }else if(status == "notfound") {
                        var seg = arguments[2],
                            isEndNode = arguments[3];
                    }
                });
            }
```

But now i get this warning in the console:

```
Node not found: 12 jquery.dynatree.js:49
```

Adn this is the full log

```
9:12:27.862 - Dynatree._create(): version='$Version: 1.2.0$', debugLevel=2. jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.865 - DynaTree.persistence: 
Object
 jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.867 - Dynatree._load(): read tree structure... jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.868 - Dynatree._init(): send Ajax request... jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.869 - Class.create.removeChildren(false) jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.876 - Dynatree._load(): render nodes... jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.877 - Dynatree._load(): bind events... jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.885 - Dynatree._load(): postInit... jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.887 - Dynatree._init(): done. jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:27.889 - ui.dynatree._init() was called; no current default functionality. jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:29.483 - Removed leading root key. jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:29.484 - Class.create._loadKeyPath(12/16/17/18) jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:29.484 - Node not found: 12 jquery.dynatree.js:49
9:12:29.485 - trigger nodeLoaded.dynatree.tree._1 jquery.dynatree.js:52
9:12:29.485 - dtnode._expand(true) IGNORED - 
Class.create
 jquery.dynatree.js:52
```

So how can i load a node what tis nested in other nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer for future reference

After some debugging and help from the dynatree developers, we came up with a solution, if you want to load up a key path use an string as key and not an integer.

instead of

```
 "icon": false,
        "checkbox": false,
        "title": "xxxxxxxx",
        "key": 23,
        "type": "child"
```

use

```
 "icon": false,
        "checkbox": false,
        "title": "xxxxxxxx",
        "key": "23",
        "type": "child"
```

That way the loadkeypath function will pickup the correct path!

Comment: How do you get this string: so the path is /12/16/17/18 ? The node.getKeyPath() can not be called by me because my node is null...